# "Validation Error When Using Two Attributes for Validation"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

"Hi Team, I am working on my React project, and I have successfully added a user to my database. However, I am facing a situation where I tried to validate both the email and the identification, but only one of them is validated at a time. Additionally, when I reload my project, it adds users who already exist."  here is my code

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { email, identification } = req.body;

  UserModel.findOne({ $or: [{ email: email, identification: identification }] })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (user.email === email && user.identification === identification) {
          res.json("El correo y la identificación ya existen");
        } else if (user.email === email) {
          res.json("El correo ya existe");
        } else if (user.identification === identification) {
          res.json("La identificación ya existe");
        }
      } else {
        UserModel.create(req.body)
          .then(newUser => res.json(newUser))
          .catch(err => res.json(err));
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

I tried several things, several ways of validation such as this one

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { email, identification } = req.body;

  UserModel.findOne({ email: email })
    .then(userWithEmail => {
      UserModel.findOne({ identification: identification })
        .then(userWithIdentification => {
          if (userWithEmail && userWithIdentification) {
            res.json("El correo y la identificación ya existen");
          } else if (userWithEmail) {
            res.json("El correo ya existe");
          } else if (userWithIdentification) {
            res.json("La identificación ya existe");
          } else {
            UserModel.create(req.body)
              .then(newUser => res.json(newUser))
              .catch(err=> res.json(err));
          }
        })
        .catch(err=> res.json(err));
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

Comment: try adding return before res.json(), for example return res.json("El correo y la identificación ya existen"); do that for every res.json statement

Comment: In the first code ,try changing the mongodb query to `{ $or: [{ email: email}, {identification: identification }] }` . Or else you can just use `{ $or: [{email}, {identification }] }`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, identification } = req.body;

  try {
    const existingEmailUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    const existingIdentificationUser = await UserModel.findOne({ identification });

    if (existingEmailUser && existingIdentificationUser) {
      return res.json("El correo y la identificación ya existen");
    } else if (existingEmailUser) {
      return res.json("El correo ya existe");
    } else if (existingIdentificationUser) {
      return res.json("La identificación ya existe");
    } else {
      const newUser = await UserModel.create(req.body);
      return res.json(newUser);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
});
```

In this code:

We use async/await to simplify the code and make it easier to read.

We first check if there is an existing user with the provided email and another with the provided identification using separate queries.

If both already exist, we return the message "El correo y la identificación ya existen."

If only one of them exists, we return the appropriate message for that case.

If neither email nor identification already exist, we create a new user and return the new user's data.

Comment: Thank you very much It works perfectly! I appriciate it